Ring theoretical aspects of the DAHA
The double affine Hecke algebras (DAHA) were introduced by Cherednik in his study of Macdonald's inner product conjectures (which were solved affirmatively).
Nowdays there are many variations of the theme, such as degenerate (trigonometric) DAHA, and the famous rational Cherednik algebras (double degeneration of the DAHA).
Most papers I know about the DAHA discusses its representation theory and relation to other branches of mathematics such as combinatorics or special functions. I am interested in results and papers that deal with it from a structure theory of rings point of view.
In particular, I watched a talk by P. Etingof where he says that the DAHA are a particular example of his theory of (sheafs of) Cherednik algebras in an arbitrary smooth variety and arbitrary (non-linear) finite group , but the details I could not find anywhere.
It would be of help if I can get some answer saying what is currently known about the ring theoretical aspects of the DAHA, or direct me to relevant papers.

What “ring theoretic properties” of the DAHA in particular are you interested in? If we look at something simpler, like the group algebra of a Weyl group, what interesting structure as a ring does it have?

@SamHopkins is it primitive? Semipriprimitive? Or may be prime or semiprime? Is it Noetherian? Is it Goldie? What is its Gelfand-Kirillov dimension? And what about the Krull dimension of Gabriel-Rentschler? Do we know its center?

Well again, do you know the answers to these questions for group algebras?

@SamHopkins Yes
